# Validate xml with dtd

Tags: c#, xml, validation, dtd

I just want to see if xml is valid with dtd and to print error message if it is not. I wrote this validator. The problem it that it prints always that document is valid, even it is not valid. Thanks for help.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Schema; 


namespace XMLValidator
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {


            var messages = new StringBuilder();
            var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD };
            settings.ValidationEventHandler += (sender, args) => messages.AppendLine(args.Message);
            var reader = XmlReader.Create("file.xml", settings);


            if (messages.Length > 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Document is not valid!");
            }
            else
                Console.WriteLine("Document is valid!");
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.WriteLine("Problem is not clear!")` :D 'doesn't work' is never a sufficient description of a problem...

Comment: How your XML and the corresponding DTD look like, and how you linked the two?

Comment: <!DOCTYPE rootNode SYSTEM "file.dtd"> with this row in my xml file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You also need to enable DTD processing

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD, DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse };
```

and of course you need to parse through the file using e.g.

```
while (reader.Read()) {}
```

Also if the DTD is in an external file then also set

```
var settings = new XmlReaderSettings { ValidationType = ValidationType.DTD, DtdProcessing = DtdProcessing.Parse, XmlResolver = new XmlUrlResolver() };
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Martin but it still prints only "Document is valid" always. :)

Comment: @Sardothien, you also need to parse through the XML.

Comment: Thanks, Martin! The problem was that dtd is external file. :) :) :)

Comment: I am looking at a way to handle the validation event throw out in the process, do you know anyway I can check to see if settings.ValidationEventHandler caught any validation event?

Comment: +1 for the external DTD file: the XmlResolver must be set even in case of SYSTEM DTD embedded with full path to the resource. This is not clear at all from docs, if you don't explicitly open the XmlResolver help page. Look out.