# C# Parse Dynamic xML into objects and return as JSON

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, xml, parsing

I have XML payloads in blob storage and am looking for the best way to parse this into classes in C#. I want to be able to parse the XML in an API and return json objects based on the XML payload however, I am unsure the best approach to start this.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Answered, edited anmy answer recently, added dynamic json generation code sample and dynamic class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Read the [documentation](http://xml.cxml.org/current/cXMLGettingStarted.pdf),
2. You can use [XmlDocument](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmldocument?view=netframework-4.7.2) and use [ValidationType.DTD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.validationtype?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_ValidationType_DTD) in DTD processing with [XmlReaderSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.dtdprocessing?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_DtdProcessing_Parse) to parse and validate XML document agains DTDs
3. Look into simiar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37361866/validate-xml-with-dtd)
4. You can use [NewtonSoft JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json#) serialization library to serialize objects into JSON format
5. Additionally, you can use dynamically generated JSON,

```cs
class cXMLJsonNode : Dictionary<string,object> 
{
}
```

to create custom built JSON object:

```cs
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new cXMLJsonNode {
  { key1, value1 },
  { key2, value2 },
  { property1, new cXMLJsonNode {
    { key1, oldValue1 } 
    { key2, oldValue1 } 
  },
  { property2, new cXMLJsonNode {
    { key1, newValue1 } 
    { key2, new cXMLJsonNode {
      { key1, newValue1 } 
      { key2, newValue2 } 
    }
  },
})
```